# How to mock Message.creator(to, from, smsRequest.getMessage()).create(); method in Twilio

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, twilio

I have used twilio to send sms to my users using Java 8 and Spring. So I want Unit test my code using JUnit5 and Mockito. But the issue is that I am unable to mock this code 
`Message.creator(to, from, smsRequest.getMessage()).create();`

So I would require help in successfully mocking this code for properly Unit testing my function.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce an interface or abstract class *between* the twilio concrete implementation of Message.creator and your code that is using it. By doing so you can use standard mocking frameworks like mockito to create the mocks for you. And in the production setup you will inject code that uses the real implementation. For this you can use standard IOC tools, or go with constructor injection.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I think the implementation is where it gets difficult here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Message.creator(to, from, smsRequest.getMessage()).create();
```

returns a MessageCreator class, which actually does the job of sending the message.

Let's say your class has a method named sendMessage which calls

```
Message.creator(...).create().
```

Then, create a class that extends the actual class and overrides the sendMessage. In this way, you can quickly put the mock of MessageCreator class.

```
...
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account
...
      @Test
    void testMockCreateOfTwilio() {
      //given
      messageCreator = mock(MessageCreator.class);
    
      MyClassUnderTest underTest = new MyClassUnderTest();   
      underTest.setMessageCreator(messageCreator);
    
      //when
      //For example You can throw an exception with your mock
      when(messageCreator.create()).thenThrow(ApiException.class);
         
      underTest.sendMessage(new SomerParams);
    
      //then
      ....  
    }
    
    
    class MyClassUnderTest extends MyActualClass {
    
      MessageCreator messageCreator;
    
      public Message sendMessage(SomeParams params) {
           return this.messageCreator.create();
       }
    
       public void setMessageCreator(MessageCreator messageCreator) {
           this.messageCreator = messageCreator;
       }
    }
```